# Having issue with checking membership in Telegram bot api

Tags: telegram

How to check if specific user has joined my channel or not in Telegram bot api

I tried `bot.get_chat_members(user_id, chat_id)` and it doesn't work.

Got bad request error.

What I made wrong? And why it doesn't work:)

Thanks!